# Where is the doc for "data" payload in FCM push system?

Tags: android, react-native-fcm

I'm setting up notifications for my app but I can't find the corresponding doc. 
Initialy I was looking for setting the smallIcon in my notifications but it was impossible until I found a message on a github repository with the following settings given which contains the `smallIcon` property. 
Now I'm trying to stack my notifs by setting the `tag` property but it does not work as expected so I'm trying to find the full documentation of that.
I can't believe google has no full doc online but I can't find what I want [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#notification-payload-support).

Maybe someone know ?
Thanks

EDIT: [The lib I'm using cannot stack notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/298). I'm going to do some ugly workaround on serverside to avoid updating my app.

Comment: The Android notification properties for the "new" HTTP v1 API are [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification).

Comment: Thanks that's was were I where but unfortunately the issue comes from the lib I'm using